# accessing property inside gradle's buildscript

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a property assigned to project and I can access the property outside the buildscript.  However, I cannot access that specific property inside the buildscript - any thoughts on how I can go about doing that?

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            credentials {
                username '$project.nexusUsername'
                password '$project.nexusPassword'
            }
            if (project.version.endsWith("-SNAPSHOT")) {
                url '$project.url'
            } else {
                url "$project.other.url"
            }
        }
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

**Update**
buildscript appears to run before any other task (and it seems as before any properties files are read) and it does not seem like one can make the buildscript depend on another task.  I simply removed the nexus information from the buildscript as it was not needed.

Comment: You're right. `buildscript` block is evaluated at the very beginning of gradle run. Properties between script and buildscript are not interchangeable - is your problem already solved?

Comment: yes, i will add as an answer in case it helps someone else.  It was not clear to me right away that one cannot read any properties file and make it available in the buildscript - hopefully it helps others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

buildscript appears to run before any other task (and it seems as before any properties files are read) and it does not seem like one can make the buildscript depend on another task. I simply removed the nexus information from the buildscript as it was not needed & was able to run gradle tasks successfully after the change.